# I am trying to do input for array that's checking duplicate values

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, duplicates

Here's what I have :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/duplicates-aas5zs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html
I have little problem. It has to find duplicate values and print them below. Any help ?

I am new in arrays so maybe anyone could help ? I tried google...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to write numbers in that input and print out duplicated numbers?

Or you need to know duplicated numbers into an Array?

By the way you don't need to use includes' input because you are already using ngModel, so you already have that value on your logic (.ts file)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem about that:

You can work on digits from 0 to 9 with this solution, but you will ignore 2-digits numbers, like "10".

By the way, if you just need a duplicated digit finder:

In your .ts, create a new method (or adjust one of yours):

```
inputNumbersString = '';
  duplicatesResult = [];

      findDuplicates(): void {
        const arrOfDigits = Array.from(String(this.inputNumbersString), Number);
        this.duplicatesResult = arrOfDigits.filter(
          (item, index) => index !== arrOfDigits.indexOf(item)
        );
        console.log(this.duplicatesResult);
      }
```

From input tag you are getting a string, so you have to convert that string into number and then divide the number into digits, after that you check if there are duplicated number and console.log them. More importantly, you assign the result to variable "duplicatesResult" which you will use into your HTML.

In your HTML:

remove the ng-container and *ngFor which wraps the input, with that you are going to create N-inputs for every array element and you don't need this.

Here your new input and button, now button calls findDuplicates on click, notice that you don't need an input value because you have all the data into the .ts file already:

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="inputNumbersString" placeholder="Insert numbers please" />
    <button (click)="findDuplicates()">CHECK DUPLICATES</button>
    <span>{{ duplicatesResult }}</span>
```

The span will order the output.

Now you can re-active the "checked" mechanic if you want, you just have to check duplicatesResult.lenght

Comment: Thank you for you answer. So what if I would like to find triplicates number instead duplicate ?

Comment: Also now i Have something like this: NaN,2,NaN,2,NaN,NaN,6,NaN,NaN

Comment: if you want to find triplicates or more, after you convert string into array of numbers you have not to filter anymore but you have to do a foreach and count for every instance how much times it appears, if 2+, then you print it.

If you have not only numbers I suggest to skip the string-> Number conversion and split string into array of strings and check if there are two equal strings. Remember that with your actual input, the string NaN is ['N','a','N'], or if you want to consider it as "undefined" it's still different.

Comment: Still not get it.  I had to change --> duplicatesResult : number[] = []; Can't i just use if (the same number are more than 3 console log this ? Also i tried to do something with this NaN but I failed. https://stackblitz.com/edit/duplicates-aas5zs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: First of all I suggest again to clean up your HTML code, you are still for-cycling the input tag, this will create chaos with big inputs/array length.

You have to use a counter when you cycle to count if a digit appears more than 2 times, then put it into the array or console.log it.

Comment: Also if you want to get more complex strings (2+ digits) and analyze them as one word, you need to implement a system of words into the input separeted by a character, so for example: 1, NaN, 4, Luke, Banana, 18, and so on... so you can split the string when your code will found a "," and from there you can have the same code that check the occurrency of the more complexed string.

Comment: Okay now looks better i tried also Foreach and counter and also failed.

Comment: I posted for you a new code into a reply, check if it resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the "NaN" part, but here a multiple occurancy checker:

**.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="inputString" placeholder="Insert digits here please" />
<button (click)="findOccurancyWanted()">Check if there are more than {{ occurancyToCheck }} occurance</button>
<div *ngFor="let result of resultsArray">
  <span>{{ result }}</span>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  private inputString = '';
  private alreadyCheckedDigits: any[] = []; // we use this because we don't want the same digit counted more than 1 time
  private occurancyToCheck = 3; // this is the number from where you want to start checking
  public resultsArray = []; // 

  findOccurancyWanted(): void {
    const inputStringIntoArray = Array.from(this.inputString);

    inputStringIntoArray.forEach((digit) => {
      if (!this.alreadyCheckedDigits.includes(digit)) {
      const occurancyCounter = this.inputString.split(digit).length - 1; //check the number of occurance are present into the string

      this.alreadyCheckedDigits.push(digit); // we add to alreadyCheckedDigits array the digit checked

      if (occurancyCounter >= this.occurancyToCheck) {
        this.resultsArray.push(digit);
      }
    }
    });
  }
}
```

So basically: you use **occurancyToCheck** variable to set how many occurance do you want to check, then when you press the button, you get the input string, for every digit you check its occurance into user's string and return a number, if the results it's equal or bigger that occurancyToCheck you put it into the **resultsArray** array, also before that you use another array, **alreadyCheckedDigits**, to check that you are not checking the same digit twice.

Now this works also for letters and every digit possible, not only numbers anymore.

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, so what about number over 10 ?

Comment: For number or strings over 2-digits you have to create some kind of divider which you can use for understand where to separate strings/numbers from each other, so something like ',', for example: "1, 3, hello, 5" so after every comma you know there is a new string